# Ubuntu 14 LTS with SX tools installation issues

Tags: ubuntu, error, installation, python

I'm trying to install the SX (http://SX.dyne.org) tools using Ubuntu 14 LTS following the installation instructions (http://sx.dyne.org/introduction.html#installation).

1. I use **wget** to download the SH script to root, then...
2. install with `sudo bash ./install-sx.sh`

All goes well until this point (terminal window output edited for brevity ie the start if the installation looks fine):

```
checking for CURL... yes
checking for libsecp256k1... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating include/bitcoin/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating libbitcoin.pc
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libsecp256k1
Making all in include/bitcoin
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/src/libbitcoin-git/include/bitcoin'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/libbitcoin-git/include/bitcoin'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/src/libbitcoin-git/src'
  CXX      utility/ec_keys.lo
utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'libbitcoin::ec_point libbitcoin::secret_to_public_key(const ec_secret&, bool)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:66:23: error: 'secp256k1_ecdsa_pubkey_create' was not declared in this scope
             compressed))
                       ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::verify_public_key(const ec_point&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:75:78: error: 'secp256k1_ecdsa_pubkey_verify' was not declared in this scope
     return secp256k1_ecdsa_pubkey_verify(public_key.data(), public_key.size());
                                                                              ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::verify_private_key(const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:81:60: error: 'secp256k1_ecdsa_seckey_verify' was not declared in this scope
     return secp256k1_ecdsa_seckey_verify(private_key.data());
                                                            ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_tweak_add(libbitcoin::ec_point&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:115:73: error: 'secp256k1_ecdsa_pubkey_tweak_add' was not declared in this scope
     return secp256k1_ecdsa_pubkey_tweak_add(a.data(), a.size(), b.data());
                                                                         ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_multiply(libbitcoin::ec_point&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:121:73: error: 'secp256k1_ecdsa_pubkey_tweak_mul' was not declared in this scope
     return secp256k1_ecdsa_pubkey_tweak_mul(a.data(), a.size(), b.data());
                                                                         ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_add(libbitcoin::ec_secret&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:127:64: error: 'secp256k1_ecdsa_privkey_tweak_add' was not declared in this scope
     return secp256k1_ecdsa_privkey_tweak_add(a.data(), b.data());
                                                                ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_multiply(libbitcoin::ec_secret&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:133:64: error: 'secp256k1_ecdsa_privkey_tweak_mul' was not declared in this scope
     return secp256k1_ecdsa_privkey_tweak_mul(a.data(), b.data());
                                                                ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::verify_public_key(const ec_point&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:76:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::verify_private_key(const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:82:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_tweak_add(libbitcoin::ec_point&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:116:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_multiply(libbitcoin::ec_point&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:122:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_add(libbitcoin::ec_secret&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:128:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

utility/ec_keys.cpp: In function 'bool libbitcoin::ec_multiply(libbitcoin::ec_secret&, const ec_secret&)':
utility/ec_keys.cpp:134:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

make[1]: * [utility/ec_keys.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/libbitcoin-git/src'
make: * [all-recursive] Error 1
Xxxxx@ubuntu:/$ sx
The program 'sx' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install lrzsz
```

Has anyone got any idea why this is occurring and if there's a workaround? I initially had **more** issues with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS so have upgraded to 14 LTS as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [breaking API change in libsecp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin/secp256k1/commit/ae6bc76e32016063a591399a7a2d7bac646603bc) that hasn't been addressed in libbitcoin's master branch. It has been addressed on their [`develop` branch](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/commit/aa39fd68b9042a341ae8a50bcd5941327a55acac) if you want to go down that road.

I have had the most luck with mastercoin's [install-sx.sh](https://github.com/mastercoin-MSC/install-msc/blob/master/res/install-sx.sh) script that pulls from older un-tagged commits that seem to work in harmony.

Comment: It works! Thank you for sharing the knowledge. I'd recommend all Windows users run a Virtual Machine/installation of Ubuntu 14 LTS to use SX, Pybitcointools and all other Python BTC utilities to their full extent (Windows is close to impossible)