# pycoin command line transaction

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoind, private-key, python

Is there a quick way to do transactions knowing only the private key(secret exponent) and the destination address, preferably from a command line utility such as pycoin?

I am using Debian/Ubuntu and python 2.7.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what OS and Python version you're using. Assuming Win/Posix, Python 2.7 pybitcointools has an excellent CLI. Although I do agree that Pycoin is a great tool for simplicity. More complicated usage cases under posix could use SX/libbitcoin

Comment: I am currently using Ubuntu with python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a transaction, you need the blockchain, or at least the transactions in the blockchain that belong to a particular address (technical term would be unspent transaction outputs or UTXOs for a particular script). There are three ways this can happen:

1. You have a local bitcoind or btcd installed which would let you query for transactions, at the expense of downloading the entire blockchain.
2. You use an electrum or some other SPV server to query for transactions, at the expense of connecting to these nodes.
3. You use a centralized service such as blockchain.info to gather all transactions at the expense of having to trust the centralized service to be up all the time and to not be corrupt.

Any way you slice it, you cannot get the transaction data from a python library that doesn't connect to some other service. Hence tools like pybitcointools or pycoin will not get you what you need. sx has some tools to look up utxos using method #3.

You can install Armory or bitcoind and import the private key and use method #1 above or use something like [pi-wallet](http://www.pi-wallet.com) and use method #2.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu, Python 2.7 (same setup as me) I'd highly recommend either:

1. [pybitcointools](http://www.github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/) (install using *pip install pybitcointools* for version 1.1.15 or *pip install bitcoin* for version 1.1.25 (recommended)
2. [sx](http://sx.dyne.org)/libbitcoin. [Might need to install using mastercoin's *install.sh* script](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32219/ubuntu-14-lts-with-sx-tools-installation-issues/32411#32411), depending on whether dependencies work (I had issues using Tasty Tahr Ubuntu 14.04).

Both are CLIs, and both work similarly allowing piping of variables, etc. However *pybitcointools* seems to support the *address history* function (API call to Blockchain.info/Blockr.io) and the [support documentation for *pybitcointools*](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/blob/master/README.txt) seems to be more self-explanatory than the brief *sx* tutorial.

Comment: +1 Do you happen to have an example of how to perform a transaction knowing only the WIF and a destination address?

Comment: From the manual page it is not very clear to me how the destination address is specified.

Comment: Sure. I'll do it once I'm off iOS. I'll need to play around and I'll post it here in ~12hrs

Comment: @Sebi just to clarify, you want to create a raw Txn and send BTC from your address (ie private key) to another address, right?

Comment: yes that is what I want

Comment: OK, I'll edit accordingly. SX tools is how I have gone about it in the past. Read https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32219/ubuntu-14-lts-with-sx-tools-installation-issues/32411#32411 if you're having dependency issues as I'll put procedures for both SX and pybitcointools

Comment: See http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/35889/9382

Answer (score 2):

Using SX tools.

At bash command line, create a WIF private key file called `private.key` for 1MBngSqZbMydscpzSoehjP8kznMaHAzh9y with this data inside:  `5HvofFG7K1e2aeWESm5pbCzRHtCSiZNbfLYXBvxyA57DhKHV4U3`. FYI, the private key (as discussed [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32628/redeeming-a-raw-transaction-step-by-step-example-required/32695#32695)) is a brainwallet of *mrbubbymrbubbymrbubby!* (which is cool, because 1MB ≈ brainwallet phrase)

OK, now we run these aliases/commands in the exact order given (node comments explaining each step):

1. `DECODED_ADDR=$(cat private.key | sx addr | sx decode-addr) # hash160`
2. `PREVOUT_SCRIPT=$(sx rawscript dup hash160 [ $DECODED_ADDR ] equalverify checksig)  # hash160 + script padding`
3. `SIGNATURE=$(cat private.key | sx sign-input txfile.tx 0 $PREVOUT_SCRIPT)   # 72 digit der signature`
4. `SIGNATURE_AND_PUBKEY_SCRIPT=$(sx rawscript [ $SIGNATURE ] [ $(cat private.key | sx pubkey) ])  # 278 digit script/sig/pubkey`
5. `sx set-input txfile.tx 0 $SIGNATURE_AND_PUBKEY_SCRIPT > txfile.tx.signed    # 192 digit signed txn`

In this instance, the aliases give the following:

- `DECODED_ADDR=dd6cce9f255a8cc17bda8ba0373df8e861cb866e`
- `PREVOUT_SCRIPT=76a914dd6cce9f255a8cc17bda8ba0373df8e861cb866e88ac`
- `SIGNATURE=3045022100da43201760bda697222002f56266bf65023fef2094519e13077f777baed553b102205ce35d05eabda58cd50a67977a65706347cc25ef43153e309ff210a134722e9e01`
- `SIGNATURE_AND_PUBKEY_SCRIPT=483045022100da43201760bda697222002f56266bf65023fef2094519e13077f777baed553b102205ce35d05eabda58cd50a67977a65706347cc25ef43153e309ff210a134722e9e0141042daa93315eebbe2cb9b5c3505df4c6fb6caca8b756786098567550d4820c09db988fe9997d049d687292f815ccd6e7fb5c1b1a91137999818d17c73d0f80aef9`

**FINAL SIGNED TXN:**

Here's the final raw Txn which sends BTC to 14zWNsgUMmHhYx4suzc2tZD6HieGbkQi5s.

`0100000001be66e10da854e7aea9338c1f91cd489768d1d6d7189f586d7a3613f2a24d5396000000008b483045022100da43201760bda697222002f56266bf65023fef2094519e13077f777baed553b102205ce35d05eabda58cd50a67977a65706347cc25ef43153e309ff210a134722e9e0141042daa93315eebbe2cb9b5c3505df4c6fb6caca8b756786098567550d4820c09db988fe9997d049d687292f815ccd6e7fb5c1b1a91137999818d17c73d0f80aef9ffffffff0123ce0100000000001976a9142bc89c2702e0e618db7d59eb5ce2f0f147b4075488ac00000000`

File Contents:

private.key = `5HvofFG7K1e2aeWESm5pbCzRHtCSiZNbfLYXBvxyA57DhKHV4U3`
txfile.tx = `0100000001be66e10da854e7aea9338c1f91cd489768d1d6d7189f586d7a3613f2a24d53960000000000ffffffff0123ce0100000000001976a9142bc89c2702e0e618db7d59eb5ce2f0f147b4075488ac00000000`
rawscript.sigpubkey.tx = `473044022054f60e8ae19411541597167362d12fc132e081a546c766bfd69c16d9d58e268a022048055c7fd8bf78e48543e8756bb3b26336df35b812a184119ba0e9d525bbb8aa0141042daa93315eebbe2cb9b5c3505df4c6fb6caca8b756786098567550d4820c09db988fe9997d049d687292f815ccd6e7fb5c1b1a91137999818d17c73d0f80aef9`
signed.tx = `0100000001be66e10da854e7aea9338c1f91cd489768d1d6d7189f586d7a3613f2a24d5396000000000b00000c0000000000000000ffffffff0123ce0100000000001976a9142bc89c2702e0e618db7d59eb5ce2f0f147b4075488ac00000000`

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of transaction on `testnet`(https://github.com/suhailvs/bitcoin-code/tree/testnet), you need `private key`,`destination address` and `previous transacion hash` which has output address which relate to the given privatekey::

```
import hashlib
import txnUtils
from keyUtils import keyToAddr, addrToScriptPubkey

# From --> one input
privateKey = hashlib.sha256('abcdefghijklmnop').hexdigest() # mpSyb71528U8dQjuTCeDCcJqH8dQTyY13c
from_address= keyToAddr(privateKey,testnet=True)
txn_hash = "3c24ca820100153fb43434191d10464dd2dcd13f0c9aa07d15f7330e8bcd0596"

# To --> android testnet wallet
to_address = 'miD4PnSDWC2M725hvFBoBhNn8fbowoHnnS'

# Sign the Transction
signed_txn = txnUtils.makeSignedTransaction(
    privateKey, txn_hash, 0, addrToScriptPubkey(from_address), # input: has balance 0.01btc
    [[900000,addrToScriptPubkey(to_address)]] # outputs: 0.009btc 
)

print 'SIGNED TXN', signed_txn

# Broadcast this transaction(ie: signed_txn) at:
# https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/tx/send
```